# Break long titles (containing file paths) with BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, biber, zotero

I am currently trying to get linebreaks inside long bibliography entry titles which have no whitespace to break at.

Let us assume that we have the following MWE with its minimal bibliography entry (this is just an example, the real entries would have more information of course) which should be displayed correctly:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@software{key,
  title = {Software repository: /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/src/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/SuperfluousWhitespaceSniff.php},
  author = {Sherwood, Greg},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Currently the whole bibliography entry takes one line in the output only and is not shown completely. I think the best way to break the entry would be at one of the slashes.

The `.bib` file itself is being created using Zotero and might be overwritten. I could edit the title manually in Zotero (which is not portable across multiple documents) or modify the exported file (which might be overwritten again later on), but these are not the best options in my opinion.

Is there anything I can do about this which does not require manual modifications of the `.bib` file?

Comment: Basically I think the only sensible way to typeset something like this is to use a command like `url.sty`'s `\url` (`\newcommand*{\filepath}{}\DeclareUrlCommand\filepath{\urlstyle{same}}` and then `title = {Software repository: \filepath{/usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/src/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/SuperfluousWhitespaceSniff.php}},` but of course that requires changes to the `.bib` file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define a new command based on `url.sty`'s `\url` for file paths.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{url}
\newcommand*{\filepath}{}
\DeclareUrlCommand\filepath{\urlstyle{same}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@software{key,
  title  = {Software repository: \filepath{/usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/src/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/SuperfluousWhitespaceSniff.php}},
  author = {Sherwood, Greg},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{key}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Greg Sherwood. Software repository: /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/src/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/SuperfluousWhitespaceSniff.php]

I am aware that this does not meet the "I don't want to modify the `.bib` file" desideratum, but I think in this case this is the most sensible thing to do. LaTeX just needs some markup to know what to do with the file path. You wouldn't expect LaTeX to hyphenate French phrases according to French rules in an otherwise English document unless you explicitly mark up the French phrase.

---

If you insist on a solution without changes to the `.bib` file you can run the following with LuaLaTeX. It replaces every occurrence of `/` with a breakable slash.

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\breakslash}{/\penalty\exhyphenpenalty\hspace{0pt}}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function replaceslash (s) 
   s = string.gsub (s, "/", "\\breakslash " )
   tex.sprint (s)
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand{\replaceslash}[1]{\directlua{replaceslash(\luastringN{#1})}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\replaceslash{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@software{key,
  title  = {Software repository: /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/src/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/SuperfluousWhitespaceSniff.php},
  author = {Sherwood, Greg},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{key}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Or *much*, *much* more fragile, some code that assumes that everything starting with `/` up to the next space is a file path.

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{url}
\newcommand*{\filepath}{}
\DeclareUrlCommand\filepath{\urlstyle{same}}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function replaceslash (s) 
   s = string.gsub (s, "(/[^%s]*)", "\\filepath{%1}" )
   tex.sprint (s)
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand{\replaceslash}[1]{\directlua{replaceslash(\luastringN{#1})}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\replaceslash{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@software{key,
  title  = {Software repository: /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/src/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/SuperfluousWhitespaceSniff.php},
  author = {Sherwood, Greg},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{key}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems like manual modifications to the exported file are not necessary when using Zotero with the [Better BibTeX](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex) addon. As I just found out, there is a way to preserve LaTeX syntax by just setting the following modified title and exporting the `.bib` file afterwards: `Software repository: <pre>\filepath{/usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/src/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/SuperfluousWhitespaceSniff.php}</pre>`. The result will be the same as in your first snippet.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh Oh yeah. With BetterBibTeX you can usually get Zotero to export even more complex data correctly.